# Toggle monitoring clipboard in C# WinForm app

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard

Currently I've an app which monitors windows clipboard. If there is any change, it displays clipboard text in a textbox. I'm using the following code found by googling-

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
protected static extern int SetClipboardViewer(int hWndNewViewer);

[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool ChangeClipboardChain(IntPtr hWndRemove, IntPtr hWndNewNext);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

IntPtr nextClipboardViewer;       

public frmMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    nextClipboardViewer = (IntPtr)SetClipboardViewer((int)this.Handle);
}

protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
{
    // defined in winuser.h
    const int WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD = 0x308;
    const int WM_CHANGECBCHAIN = 0x030D;

    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD:
                DisplayClipboardData();
                SendMessage(nextClipboardViewer, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
            break;

        case WM_CHANGECBCHAIN:
            if (m.WParam == nextClipboardViewer)
                nextClipboardViewer = m.LParam;
            else
                SendMessage(nextClipboardViewer, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
            break;

        default:
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            break;
    }
}
```

The above code works fine. But now I would to handle it dynamically. Something like-

```
private void chkToggleMonitor_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkToggleMonitor.CheckState==CheckState.Checked)
    {
        //Monitor clipboard
    }
    else
    {
        //Don't monitor clipboard
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do it based on the current clipboard code?
Thanks.

Comment: Is the method DisplayClipBoardData used to display the data in the textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the application to Windows Clicpboard listener use:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool AddClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd);
```

And to remove it from the list use:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool RemoveClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd);
```

Eventually you can use it in your code, like this:

```
if (chkToggleMonitor.CheckState==CheckState.Checked)
{
    AddClipboardFormatListener(this.Handle);
}
else
{
    RemoveClipboardFormatListener(this.Handle);
}
```